# PyTorch loss function evaluation

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I am trying to optimise a function (`fit`) using the acceleration of `GPU` in `PyTorch`. This is the straight `Python` code, where I doing the evaluation of `fit`:

```
import numpy as np 
...
for j in range(P):
    e[:,j] = z - h[:,j];
    fit[j] = 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma*N)*np.sum(exp(-(e[:,j]**2)/(2*sigma**2)));
```

> The dimension of the variables are: 
>   `z`[Nx1], `h`[NxP], `e`[NxP], `fit`[1xP]. 
>   where `P` is the number of dimension of `fit` and `N` is the length of each dimension.
>
> I am aware that `for` loops should be avoided, so where it is my attempt to do it using `PyTorch` through `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`.

```
import torch 
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor
e     = z - h;
fit   = 1/(torch.sqrt(2*pi)*sigma*N)*torch.sum(torch.exp(-(torch.pw(e,2))/(2*torch.pow(sigma,2))));
```

> Unfortunately it is not working. What is wrong? 
>   Thank you!

Comment: what is the error message? always post question with error information. I guess you are encountering size mismatch error at line `e = z - h`, is it correct?

Comment: Sorry about it. Next time I'll post the error message. Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting size mismatch error at the following line.

```
e = z - h
```

In your example, `z` is a vector (2d tensor of shape `Nx1`) and `h` is a 2d tensor of shape `NxP`. So, you can't directly subtract `h` from `z`.

You can do the following to avoid size mismatch error.

```
e = z.expand(*h.size()) - h
```

Here, `z.expand(*h.size())` will convert the tensor `z` from `Nx1` to `NxP` shape by duplicating the column vector `P` times.